# @compatibility_alias can call instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, compatibility

I'm doing some tests with @compatibility_alias, and realized that:

> With it we can change the name of our class, but compensating you can only access static methods (+).

My doubt is: @compatibility_alias can access instance methods (-)? or it is restricted only static methods (+)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't access instance methods using a class name, but using an instance. So for example with:

```
@compatibility_alias BaArray NSMutableArray
```

there is no more need to access `addObject:` via `BaArray` than there is via `NSMutableArray`. The above can be used as:

```
BaArray *ba = [BaArray new];  // allocates an NSMutableArray
[ba addObject:@42];           // adds an object to the NSMutableArray
```

The instance method call does not mention `BaArray` or `NSMutableArray`.

Note: this feature is not designed to "change the name of our class", but for situations where a class name has changed and there is a desire to use existing source which contains the old name.

HTH